# Apply image map to a background image via jquery only

Tags: jquery, imagemap

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pfa6F/)

Here i am trying to put an image map upon a background image via jquery only. Currently my site structure has this image set to the background of a `div` with css and i do not wish to make any changes to that. How can i **get** the background image in the body or some div as a DOM object and apply the image map to that via jquery ??
Also it will be helpful if you can tell me how can i make this image map according to my responsive site. Again i do not wish to change my existing css.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using

```
$('body img').prop('usemap','#ballMap');
```

this `body img` is actually referring to any `img` tag in your body not the css background property of the body.

You need to add an empty `img` tag to the body to make this thing work

```
<img width="420" height="315"/>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Pfa6F/2/

Comment: I created that fiddle just for the sake of example. In my question i have mentioned that in my actual scenario the image is set via CSS. I cannot use a dummy img tag inside body as i have many other images inside body and moreover i do not wish to set its width and heigth. So my actual question is that if i can **get** the background image of body or some div(getting the DOM will be better of course) and then apply the .prop() on it.